# How to diagnostic internet access failure on a linux system?

Tags: virtual-machines, linux-networking, xen, ethernet

I have a `VM` running on `Xen`. The virtual machine was running fine for months and suddently the network access broke down.

```
             Dom0                           DomU

.-------.  bridge  .-------. virtual link .------.
| eth0  |----------| vif55 |-------x------| eth0 |
'-------'          '-------'       |      '------'
                                   |
Seems to be broken somewhere here /
```

However, I can still `xm console` from `Dom0` and access the `VM`.

I would like to understand what is the origin of the problem. What I know for sure is that if I restart my `VM` everything will go back to normal (I know this because it is not the first time it happens)...

Here is what I did so far:

#### From the DomU

```
xm console domu
$ sudo su
$ ifconfig
```

Network connection looks ok. IP is ok, but either of these commands will fail:

```
$ ping dom0
$ ping 8.8.8.8
```

The error I got is:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 24002ms
```

My `fail2ban` does not look broken:

```
$ tail -n2 fail2ban.log
2015-07-31 19:41:52,851 fail2ban.actions[1854]: WARNING [ssh] Ban 218.65.30.61
2015-07-31 19:51:53,618 fail2ban.actions[1854]: WARNING [ssh] Unban 218.65.30.61

$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-apache  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fail2ban-apache (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

The available disk space given by `df` looks ok.

#### From the Dom0

The `VM` is running:

```
$xmlist | grep domu
domu                                   55  4096     4     -b---- 670393.8
```

It is connected to `vif55`:

```
$iptables -L | grep domu
ACCEPT     all  --  domu            anywhere            PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vif55.0
```

The `vif55` is available:

```
$ ifconfig | grep vif55.0
vif55.0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
          inet6 addr: xxxx::fcff:ffff:xxxx:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:60965324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:130097868 errors:0 dropped:22 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:32
          RX bytes:3441407339 (3.2 GiB)  TX bytes:161037189 (153.5 MiB)
```

The `vif55` is connected to the network bridge:

```
$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
eth0            8000.10604ba1432a       no              peth0
                                                        vif1.0
                                                        vif10.0
                                                        vif11.0
                                                        vif48.0
                                                        vif51.0
                                                        vif55.0
                                                        vif56.0
                                                        vif57.0
                                                        vif58.0
                                                        vif59.0
                                                        vif60.0
                                                        vif9.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this mystery is the error you're getting from `ping`: `sendmsg: No buffer space available`.  This means that packets aren't just being dropped somewhere, they're actually getting "clogged up" in the guest somewhere.  This is, in a physical machine, an indication that the kernel driver and/or hardware are buggy; similarly, in a VM, it means you've got low-level buggy networking code somewhere.

First off, make sure you're up to date with patches, especially on the host.  If you're running a very old release of your OS, now might be the time to upgrade that -- Xen has had a *lot* of bugs fixed over the years.

You *can*, temporarily, work around it by increasing the `net.core.wmem_max` sysctl.  However, this is not a "fix", just a workaround; presumably the larger buffer space will eventually fill up again and you'll be back where you are now.

You don't specify how you're running the guest.  If it's fully virtualised, there may be a bug in the emulated NIC you're using; the virtio one is your best bet, but if you're already using it try the `e1000` instead.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This server will need for sure an upgrade but I am afraid of doing it. It might be a bit risky. How can I check how am I running my guests and if it is fully virtualised or not?  In the guest vif's config I don't have any `model` specified. How can I check which NIC I am using?

Comment: Best to ask separate questions as separate questions, rather than discussing it in comments.